# How do I as an application sys-admin monitor Verified by VISA and MasterCard SecureCode?

Tags: monitoring, dependencies

We integrate with 3 payment service providers in multiple countries, and sporadically we will get customer reports that the 3DSecure-check part of the payments-process is not working.  We've yet to get adequate reports to troubleshoot the problem or proactively warn customers that this may happen (or disable the check for the duration of a problem).

How can we directly monitor the VISA and MasterCard service-dependencies so that we can get better insight into our payments-process status?  Our PSPs do not expose the problems in a proactive way; we get problem-reports direct from customers, as I mentioned - not the best place to be in.

We're after:

1. An API-call we can periodically make to get red/green status for each system
2. A web-page we can hit to see whether the system is expected to be up/down
3. A web-page we can hit to see whether there's upcoming maintenance/down-time
4. A way of running through a test payment, but against a real live payment-card, but that won't then affect the credit rating of the card's account since we'll essentially be setting up and cancelling payment-authorisations on a several-times-a-day basis if we do that

Where can we find some/all of the ab

Answer (score 1):

I recommend some browser-based **transaction monitoring**. We are using [AlertFox](http://www.alertfox.com/) with good success  for our online store (monitoring product search, shopping cart and *credit-card/Paypal backend*). If you google for Keynote or Gomez, they also provide this service, but I never used them.

As an unrelated site note, it is unbelievable how often Paypal has sporadic issues...